# visual studio script documents

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

I have a blazor project. But when I try to debug it (visual studio 2022) the script documents always pops open. For the most part this wouldn't be a big issue if not for all the /VMxxx files that pop op and even clutter the search results (and create a performance issues)

In previous stacks I encountered the hint to disable the javascript debugging. But both in tools => options => debugging as below the green "debug" arrow this option is already disabled while those files (and their impact) keep popping up.

Anybody an idea how to resolve this? As far as I can tell/remember it's something that popped up a few weeks ago and that wasn't there earlier

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but  if other people have the same issues. The next steps seem to be the prerequisit

- as long as your not logged in the application, visual studio won't create any    /VMxxx file spam. It creates a limited number of files, but
  those are normal for debugging
- The moment you login to your blazor application you get a lot of /VM files with "unchanged" as text
- It seems to be only the case if you're working with a prerendered blazor app. in other cases it also seems stable
- There seems to be some kind of connection to /connect (and not only /authorize as in the documentation). Adding this endpoint to the serviceworker and prerender exclusions won't help
- Removing the hot reload (which creates websocket calls that could be the origin from the eval/VM files) also doesn't seem to work

If you look into the debugger at this point and you add some random pauses. One can notice that it will always pause in some kind of mono code or in the Authenticationservice.js . It seems as if the debug code and the authenicationservice.js somehow create some interference and thus fireing some contiousl event flow with an in between time of only a couple of milliseconds

The only workaround is to turn off all javascript debugging, but in the code (useWasMDebugging) as in visual studio